# How to start an AI that extracts relevant phrases from datasheets?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

in my previous question I asked something similar, but I don't know how to beginn this task.

I have to extract phrases from datasheets and as I have a ton of training data (PDFs and the according extracted information), I want to manage this via Deep Learning, as every datasheet could be different, but the structure is always similar.
But how to start? What to google? What is the term for my plans?

I hope someone has a concrete way for me.

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you're asking, but perhaps natural language processing is what you're after? Sentiment analysis? I can't provide a concrete way for you without a concrete question :)

Comment: Say we have standardized datasheets, where certain information has to be under certain paragraphs. For example there is always a product name in the first paragraph. But every vendor calls it something different, "product title" for example. The AI has to learn where the name could be and extract this particluar phrase, the product name. There are many other phrases to extract but this is the easiest one.

Comment: if the structures are very similar, you may prefer to use a regex-based parser instead of DL.

Comment: This is the current approach, but the documents are too different for a general solution.